# how to read text file as chunks determined by chunk size in matlab

Tags: matlab, file, io

I'm trying to read a text file chunk by chunk where every chunk has a size of 10KB for example..
How to do that in matlab??
BTW You can't control the content of the text file (which means you can't suggest adding a specific character to split the text file)

Comment: Looks like you need to use low-level reading with [`fread`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html). Note that `fread`'s second argument is size in bytes, and every call starts reading where you left in the predecing call

Comment: thanks but it's returning the numerical representation of the file (ex: 'a' is 97)

Comment: @user3379482 read the documentation, the [`precision`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#inputarg_precision) input allows you to specify your source and output data classes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could start by using [fread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html), and then specify that you want to read n bytes at a time- something like this, perhaps?

```
n = 10000
file = fopen(fileID)
A = zeros(n, 'uchar') --perhaps char*1 for a text file? 
A = fread(file, size(A))
```

What this should do is read 10KB, and then leave the pointer where it read the last character. If you call fread again with the same parameters, it should give you the next n bytes. I'd double check this, but I don't have a copy of Matlab at the moment.